# Deploy GTK Sharp applications to Windows without installing GTK#

Tags: c#, windows, mono, gtk#

I am developing a GTK# mono application under openSuse, but I am interested in deploying it for all three platforms (Windows 7, Snow Leopard and as many Linux distributions as I can test on).

Deploying on Linux is not a problem as GTK# comes with the mono libraries, but for Windows I would not like to force the users to install GTK#. Is there a way to embed GTK# in the application, or at least integrate its installation with the installation of my program?

Comment: you will need to re-distribute gtk+ and gtk-sharp with your installer, gimp does the same thing (since they wrote gtk it isn't a surprise)

Comment: I thought that this would be one solution. How should I go about doing so?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you can't have your users install the gtk# libraries? It's general practice for any application that relies on shared libraries.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You may deploy GTK# applications without forcing users to install GTK# for .NET on Windows in a number of ways.

1. You may **embed** the entire Mono runtime (19 MB overhead) into your Application. Then there won't be *any* dependencies, your users won't even need to install .NET or MONO. [Here's a Guide](http://www.mono-project.com/Embedding_Mono) (I think Banshee uses this).
2. You may copy all the GTK# assemblies into your program directory. It isn't recommended however because you may run into a lot of problems if the user has another version of the Gtk runtime installed. (Yes GTK+ also needs a runtime).
3. You may integrate the GTK# installer with the Windows Installer of your application. (Then your users will be able to install both with a single click, no forcing). Many Installer programs can do this.
4. You may use a [Package Management System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_management_system).
5. You may use Deployment Management / Dependency Management Software, but this is expensive since all the good ones are propriety.

Though these workarounds can save trouble for your users, in the long run I recommend option `3`. It may prove worthwhile to have your users install GTK# because other workarounds may ultimately give more inconvenience to your users than a simple extra installation.