# how to integrate the GTK# installer to my own application installer

Tags: c#, windows, installation, nsis, gtk#

According to this guide [Deploy GTK Sharp applications to Windows without installing GTK#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816895/deploy-gtk-sharp-applications-to-windows-without-installing-gtk) I decided to integrate the installer to my own installer I made using NSIS

I have a c# application which I wrote using gtk#. Now I need to install it to computers that don't have gtk# installed. I downloaded the installer of gtk# and I am executing it using:

```
ExecWait 'msiexec.exe /quiet /package "$INSTDIR\gtk-sharp-2.12.20.msi"'
```

That actually executes the installer and does something because I can see it in list of installed programs (the gtk package) but, when I try to launch the application after setup I get this error:

```
Unable to load DLL 'libgtk-win32-2.0-0.dll': The specified procedure could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007F)
```

Is there any other package I need to install to make this work? Or what is a proper way to implement the installer?

Comment: Do you have correct result if you enter teh same command by hand? (with replacing `$INSTDIR` by the correct path)

Comment: well, that is hard to test I don't have unlimited number of windows machines that never had this package installed on... but given that I can see it installed and that all files are present in program files I believe it was installed just as if I did it by hand

Comment: can you see if the named dll is installed with the application executable, or somewhere in the `%path%` ?

Comment: it is in path, there is no dll at all with application