# Easiest way to make a gtk# app work on windows

Tags: c#, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop, gtk#

What I want to know is what is the easiest way to get a GTK# app running on Windows.

I want to develop in Ubuntu and then make installers for people who are running windows so they can just use my apps straight away..

Do I need to somehow bundle Mono into the installer.. maybe GTK# too..

This seems like a bit of a nightmare..

So yeah just the easiest way for me to be able to develop in monodevelop and then give people my apps without them having to do loads of tricks to make them work.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you do not use Mono specifics libraries and P/Invoke your application should run out of the box on a windows system - assuming the .NET framework is available.

Concerning how you want to ship your application and the dependencies, especially GTK#, I advise you to have a look at this question : [Deploy gtk sharp applications to windows without installing gtk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816895/deploy-gtk-sharp-applications-to-windows-without-installing-gtk). Multiple techniques are described, one of them will probably fulfill your requirements.

Comment: Okay I will have a look at that site, cheers..

I made a test application yesterday using GTK#, all it had was some labels and a toolbar and a button and it did not run on Windows straight up.. nothing happened at all when clicking the exe file

Comment: Be aware that the GTK+ runtime (native) as the GTK# assemblies need to be available on the target system. Moreover you want the GTK# version to match the underlying GTK+ runtime. In the question I linked, the third possibility of the accepted answer is the one I would choose since it would take care of that.

Answer (score -1):

Install Visual C++ 2013 redistributable package x86 and gtk# for .net.